# Serialization method

Tags: java, android, serialization, xml-serialization, restlet

I am writing android app - the client and java server. I am using restlet library. When I am running an app on my phone I get following errors in logcat:
 `11-19 13:43:53.665: E/dalvikvm(10130): Could not find class 'java.beans.XMLDecoder',          referenced from method org.restlet.representation.ObjectRepresentation.<init>`

I suppose I have to change object serialization method (I would prefer to use Java native serialization, as it's like that on the server) but I have no idea how to do it.

The code in android app:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(
    "http://192.168.1.102:8182/speedLimit"
);

resource = cr.wrap(SpeedLimitsResource.class);
coords.setLatitude(55);
coords.setLongtitude(16.5);
pack = resource.retrieve(coords);
```

pack and coords are instances of Transport classes shared between the client and server. They implement Serializable, they are in the same package.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you use android edition of restlet?

Comment: Argh, it appears I was indeed using wrong jar. Thank you very much for your comment Nikita. Maybe you can add an answer, so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use android edition for restlet: http://www.restlet.org/downloads/stable